# How to don't save search result in redux-persist in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have Top tabs that render the result data from the search request,

So I don't find any solution to pass data to tabs!

So i use redux to save result data after getting the response from API and pass it as a prop in Tabs screen.

But I have some issue I use `redux-persist` to save state locally,

But in this case, i don't want to save these data in storage, So is there a way to handle it 'just in this case (search result) '?

Code

search.js

```
 onSearch = async () => {
    const {searchText} = this.state;

        let response = await API.post('/search', {
          name: searchText,
        });
        let {
          data: {
            data: {data},
          },
        } = response;

        this.props.dispatch(getResult(data))

}
```

Songs Tab

```
{props.artists.length <= 0 ? (
        <Text style={[styles.serachFindText, {paddingVertical: 15}]}>
          Not found ☹️
        </Text>
      ) : (
        ... Flatlist ...
     )}
```

**Error**

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Action

```
import {GET_SEARCH_RESULT} from './types';
export const getResult = (songs, artists) => {
  return {
    type: GET_SEARCH_RESULT,
    songs,
    artists,
    // payload: result,
  };
};
```

Reducer

```
import {GET_SEARCH_RESULT} from '../actions/types';

let initial_state = {
  searchResult: [], // maybe it's wrong?
};
const searchResultReducer = (state = initial_state, action) => {
  const {payload, type} = action;
  switch (type) {
    case GET_SEARCH_RESULT:
      return {...state, artists: action.artists, songs: action.songs};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default searchResultReducer;
```

[image: err]

Store

```
..
import searchResultReducer from '../reducers/searchResultReducer';
..


const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ...
  searchResult: searchResultReducer,
  ...
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);



export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add the `blacklist` key to the persistConfig with an array including the keys you don't want to persist. In your case:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  blacklist: ['searchResult'],
};
```

[Check all config options for the `persistReducer` here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/api.md#type-persistconfig).

Comment: Thank you, its works, I just have some other question it's related in this case, Now the response i got from API it contains two types 'Songs, Artists' How can I pass it to one action/reducer without concatenating it And make two `reducers` ?

Comment: It really depends on the shape of your state. If both songs and artists are under `searchResults` the you can use the same reducer function to update them. But if they're each one under different keys, then you'll need to create two different actions (one for each reducer).

Comment: It's in. same response and i handle it, it's work now but if you have a best practice it will be great :) check the question again "Action, reducer - init state" because I got some error when i make a condition to check if the array length <= 0 do something but it says `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` but i dispatch the action and in debugger i can see it!

Comment: In that case it's probably because you're relying on the `artists` prop to be set, which might not be depending on the initial state you have connected. This might happen by example if your initial state for `searchResult` before you search is "undefined" (so it won't have the `artists` key) and you try to display this component before the search result is filled. You can work around it by having an initial state that has empty arrays for your keys, or by changing the condition to check using the safe navigation operator and invert the order: `props.artists?.length > 0 ? ...`

Comment: Hey @elyalvarado, can you please explain to me what `?` do in `props.artists?.length`, Is it check if artists exist or not firstly?

Comment: @DevAs `?.` is the safe navigation operator (aka elvis operator), it only evaluates the method on the right if the value on the left hand side of it is defined, otherwise it returns undefined saving you from the dreadful `Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`. So `props.artists?.length` is equivalent to `props.artists && props.artists.length` but shorter.